# what is different between xml and html parsing in lxml?

Tags: html, xml, lxml

Could someone explain what are the differences between parsing a document using html or using xml in lxml? my understanding is that html could be considered a particular "instantiation" of xml, therefore if I always selected to parse using xml I should always get correct parsing, right?

Is the difference maybe that html parser only considers as possible the html tags, while xml allows any kind of document, provided that it is structurally sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML is not an application of XML. XHTML is. HTML 4 and earlier were (but only in theory) an application of SGML. HTML 5 has its own parsing rules.

XML requires that markup be well formed (every element by have an empty element tag or a start tag and an end tag, boolean variables must be written with explicit attribute values, attribute values must be quoted).

HTML does not. Many elements can (or must) have the end tag omitted. Quotes are optional around many attribute values. etc.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, so as I understand it, lxml parsing using HTML allows for many more "not-so-well-formed" structures? this makes sense given that in the lxml documentation it is recommended to parse xhtml with the xml parser.